# Find map coordinates based on street and cross streets information

Tags: dictionary, location, coordinates, geo, geofencing

Example:

I have a street BECK STREET and two cross streets WESTCHESTER SQUARE and KIRK STREET. As well as direction W.

Result:

Need to drop a pin at this location. If it's easier I would also be ok with drawing a geofence.

What would be a good way to calculate this.